# Using split command' in Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, splitting

I have bunch of home adresses which contain home number and subnumber, for example Street of J.F. Kennedy 1005A. Now I want to split this into two fields out of home number, one for main number and one for subnumber.

How to split '1005A' and get '1005' in one and 'A' in another field somehow using the 'split command' in Field Calculator?

Comment: Is it always four numbers and a single letter?

Comment: Are you using the field calculator of ArcGIS Desktop, QGIS or something else?

Comment: Yes, 1005 and A. 

It's not always four numbers, sometimes is just 2 or 3.. but mostly is a single letter. 

I'm using field calculator of ArcGIS Desktop

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Boolean "Is it possible?" questions are of little value, since the answer is always, "Yes." Please [Edit] this question to specify the exact GIS software, restructure this to a "How" query, and contain the code you have attempted so far.

Comment: Plesse [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Python code and the [UpdateCursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) which is like a more powerful Field Calculator. The [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#) is doing the splitting of the numbers and letters.

Add the Feature Class to ArcMap, add the two fields as text (or modify the code to convert into other data types) and execute code in the Python Window. You need to change name of the feature class and fields in the code to match your data (yellow below):

[image]

```
import arcpy,re
fieldlist=['Adress','Main_number','Subnumber']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("Points123",fieldlist) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1],row[2]=re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|\d+', row[0].split()[-1])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```